# Comparing 2 Arrays using array_map?

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

I wanted to refrain from using nested foreach in my actual code, so I was thinking of using an array function *(correct me if I'm wrong)* called array_walk thinking it would replace my code in foreach.

I wanted to compare both of the WHOLE array if they one of them have the same description, but the problem is array_walk only compares the first key/index and does not go through the second index to check. is there other way? I'm just trying to optimize my code

> By the way, this code returns both *found*

```
<?php $array = array (
    '1' => array(
        'count' => '1',
        'id' => 1,
        'description' => 'Bag',

    ),
    '2' => array(
        'count' => '1',
        'id' => 2,
        'description' => 'Pencil',
    ), );

$bin = array (
    '1' => array(
        'count' => '1',
        'id' => 2,
        'description' => 'Bag',
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'count' => '1',
        'id' => 2,
        'description' => 'Pencil',
    ), );

$b = array_map(function($array, $bin) {
    if ($array['description'] == $bin['description']){
        $count = "found";
    }else{
        $count = "not found";
    }

    return array("status" => $count, "cart_array" => $array['description'], "bin"=>$bin['description']); }, $array, $bin);

var_dump($b);


?>
```

> but this one, the first array doesnt return found, it should return
>   found because there is a *pencil* and *bag* in $bin array **updated the code**

```
<?php
$array = array (
    '1' => array(
        'count' => '1',
        'id' => 1,
        'description' => 'Bag',

    ),
    '2' => array(
        'count' => '1',
        'id' => 2,
        'description' => 'Pencil',
    ),
);

$bin = array (
    '1' => array(
        'count' => '1',
        'id' => 2,
        'description' => 'Pencil',
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'count' => '1',
        'id' => 2,
        'description' => 'Bag',
    ),
);

$b = array_map(function($array, $bin)
{
    if ($array['description'] == $bin['description']){
        $count = "found";
    }else{
        $count = "not found";
    }

    return array("status" => $count, "cart_array" => $array['description'], "bin"=>$bin['description']);
}, $array, $bin);

var_dump($b);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_column` first to get all of `description` keys from `$array`. Then, you can check these values with `$bin` values.

```
$desc = array_column($array, 'description');
$b = array_map(function($array, $bin)
{
    global $desc;
    if (in_array($bin['description'], $desc)){
        $count = "found";
    }else{
        $count = "not found";
    }

    return array("status" => $count, "cart_array" => $array['description'], "bin" => $bin['description']);
}, $array, $bin);

var_dump($b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any expected output in the question but I assume you want to know the difference between them.
In the manual for array_diff there is a code called arrayRecursiveDiff which handles multidimensional arrays and outputs the difference.

```
var_dump(arrayRecursiveDiff($array, $bin));


function arrayRecursiveDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) {
  $aReturn = array();

  foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) {
    if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) {
      if (is_array($mValue)) {
        $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]);
        if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff; }
      } else {
        if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) {
          $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
        }
      }
    } else {
      $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
    }
  }
  return $aReturn;
}
```

This outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["description"]=>
    string(3) "Bag"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["description"]=>
    string(6) "Pencil"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.Nevertheless both arrays have different length or the values do not have the same position, This will work :

```
$bin_desc=array_column($bin,'description');

$b = array_map(function($array)use($bin_desc) {
    if (in_array($array['description'],$bin_desc)){
        $count = "found";
    }else{
        $count = "not found";
    }

    return array("status" => $count, "cart_array" => $array['description'], "bin"=>$array['description']); }, $array);

var_dump($b);
```